# NameError trying to use a custom class

Tags: python, python-2.7, class

I am new to Python, am just learning Classes, and am trying to write a "personal info" program:

This is my code:

```
class PersonalInfo():    
    def names(self, name):
        name = raw_input("What is your name?")
        self.names = name

    def addresses(self, add):
        add = raw_input("What is your adress?")
        self.addresses = add

    def ages(self, age):
        age = raw_input("What is your age?")
        self.ages = age

    def numbers(self, number):
        number = raw_input("What is your phone number?")
        self.numbers = number

PersonalInfo()

def print_names():
    info = PersonalInfo()
    print "Name:", info.names(name)
    print "Address:", info.addresses(add)
    print "Age:", info.info.ages(age)
    print "Phone number:", info.numbers(number)

print_names()
```

But when I run it it says this:

```
NameError: global name 'add' is not defined
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Please fix your indentation first

Comment: You should study better what is OOP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several issues with your code other than the `NameError` and I strongly suggest you read more on python classes:

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A_Beginner's_Python_Tutorial/Classes

I'll run you through those issues.

First, the `NameError` occurs because the `add` variable was not defined. The same applies to all other arguments you provided in your print statements.

Second, there are issues with the way you define the class methods:

```
class PersonalInfo():    
    def names(self, name):
        name = raw_input("What is your name?")
        self.names = name
```

Here, you are re-assigning the `name` variable to the return value of `raw_input` so there's no sense in setting it as an argument in the first place. Also, by stating `self.names = name` you are re-assigning the class method to the string that is returned by `raw_input`!

Third, you have to decide whether you want to provide the information when calling the methods, or using `raw_input`. Here's a working example of your code, assuming you want to use `raw_input`

```
class PersonalInfo():    
    def names(self):
        name = raw_input("What is your name?")
        self.name = name

    def addresses(self):
        add = raw_input("What is your adress?")
        self.address = add

    def ages(self):
        age = raw_input("What is your age?")
        self.age = age

    def numbers(self):
        number = raw_input("What is your phone number?")
        self.number = number

def print_names():
    info = PersonalInfo()
    # Get information
    info.names()
    info.addresses()
    info.ages()
    info.numbers()
    # After getting the info, print it
    print "Name:", info.name
    print "Address:", info.address
    print "Age:", info.age
    print "Phone number:", info.number

print_names()
```

Comment: Hi @ODiogoSilva, It helped me very much, but why do I need the `info.names()`  (in the `print_names`) etc.. part?

Comment: Without calling those methods, the attributes `info.name`, `info.address`, etc will not be defined, and you'll get an `AttributeError` if you try the print statements.